# Electron accelerated by gravity and electromagnetic radiation

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity

If electron (or other charged particle) is accelerated by gravity (a very weak force), it should emit electromagnetic radiation. Is there any experimental evidence that gravity does indeed cause such emissions?

Comment: Maybe if the electron were near a black hole? (Just kidding, don’t really know)

Comment: @JohnRennie which answer answered this question? The accepted answer over there does not address this question, and is highly contested even for the question there.

Comment: mkc4s, any body in space follows its geodesic path, be this a photon, a stone, a planet or the electron. Falling together with the electron towards an airless planet, both are not accelerated (you will feel weightlessness). The same is true for the circular or elliptical path of a satellite or the electron around a planet. Since Einstein there should not be any doubt about this. Acceleration means a force that pushes or brakes an object, in the freefall you are weightless and that is the reason we are not talking about an acceleration but the geodesic path.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292055/why-do-things-accelerate/292073#292073